# Standard Java webapp with optional Google App Engine support

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, tomcat, web-applications

I've built plenty of Java webapps that run in standard containers like Tomcat and Jetty, but I've never built one that runs in Google's App Engine before.  I'm using Maven, so I had originally thought that I could just do this with build profiles to just optionally include Google's libraries at build time to make an App Engine-compatible WAR.

Unfortunately, it seems to be more complex than that. In reading through the documentation, there seems to be an awful lot of very specific code you have to write in order to use the App Engine. For example, all file system writes need to go through the App Engine data store, so you can't use native `java.io.*` libraries.

I understand why these things are necessary, and I wouldn't mind having some of this code in my webapp. However, I really don't like the idea that my webapp can *only* run on the App Engine. Is it possible/feasible to write my code in such a way that I can also run it in a typical container like Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on what you app is going to do. You are going to run into troubles as soon as you want to do stuff with the datastore, or caching for example. Perhaps you could wrap things line datastore calls or caching, but certain apis, like search you can forget about. If you just want to run something locally that is no problem you can mock the app engine locally.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that you can use the SDK to run your app locally. I just really don't like the idea that my app could no longer run in a normal servlet container.

Comment: You could also split the logic, a standard container for standard stuff, or stuff that the gae does not support, for example sockets(maybe they are now supported not sure), and then GAE Servlets. The standard containers will not support loading balancing out of the box though.

Comment: That's kinda what I was afraid of. I'm still not entirely sure how much of my code will need to be isolated in that way because I'm new to it. I doubt I'm doing much that GAE can't do, but it's somewhat concerning that you need so many libraries included in your build to use it.